# Is possible to force only Deluge to connect via PPTP?

Tags: vpn, bittorrent, pptp, deluge

Is it possible to use my primary internet connection for all the traffic and force only Deluge to connect via PPTP?

Answer (score 1):

You can set an IP address for incoming connections but I think the best way for all traffic is to use iptables. There a Unix StackExchange question about setting this up: [Only allow certain outbound traffic on certain interfaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12085/8443)